# Trying to connect to web app running on 20.04 Host from Windows 10 Guest in KVM

Tags: networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I seem to recall this working OOTB with VMware Player, but it has been a while and I could be mistaken. Using `kvm2` for `minikube`, never used for other VMs, but want avoid having two hypervisors.

At any rate:

- Guest IP: `192.168.122.197`
- Host IP: `10.0.0.165`
- Web App IP (`minikube ip`): `192.168.39.128`

I've installed the latest `VirtIO` drivers.

The guest can `ping 10.0.0.165`, but the host cannot `ping 192.168.122.197`. The guest cannot `ping 192.168.39.128` as it comes back with `Destination port unreachable.`

This is the `xml` for the network adapter for the VM:

```
<interface type="network">
  <mac address="52:54:00:d9:97:d0"/>
  <source network="default" portid="30b67932-cf43-419b-bd26-5a07f451078e" bridge="virbr0"/>
  <target dev="vnet0"/>
  <model type="virtio"/>
  <alias name="net0"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x01" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</interface>
```

When I try to access the web app from a browser in the guest, it is unable to connect: `Hmmmm... can't reach this page... took too long to respond`.

What should I be doing to get this working?

Comment: Can you add output of `route` command, on your host, guest and if possible on your minikube? That looks like a network problem.